# How should I parse JSON?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse this json.

However, it is not working ...

I want to parse expected_departure_time of all the buses such as 4 , 15, C1, 4A in departure

this is my code which is not working.

```
try{


                                String str =  response.getString("departures");
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(str);
                                JSONObject bus = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                String four =  bus.getString("expected_departure_time");
                                textView.append(four);                 
                               }catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                               }
```

JSON

https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/stop/6090282/live.json?app_id=d7180b02&app_key=47b460aac35e55efa666a99f713cff28&group=route&nextbuses=yes

Comment: This will not be the full answer, only a short tip, search after Gson :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're making is that you're considering "departures" as a JsonArray, which is not the case in your JSON example, it is a JsonObject (Which in my opinion is a poor way of constructing this Json).
Anyway, you will have to get all the JsonObjects inside the "departure" JsonObject by doing this:

```
try
{   
    String jsonString=response.toString();
    JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(jsonString).getJSONObject("departures");
    Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() )
    {
        String key = keys.next();
        JSONArray innerJArray = jObject.getJSONArray(key);
        //This is your example, you can add a loop here
        innerJArray(0).getString("expected_departure_time");
    }
}
catch (JSONException e)
{   e.printStackTrace();    }
```

Comment: thanks I slightly changed due to innerJArray(0).getString("expected_departure_time");   sth like  JSONObject bus = innerJArray.getJSONObject(1);

                                        String hi =  bus.getString("line");
                                        String four =  bus.getString("aimed_departure_time");
                                        textView.append(hi+"  "+four+"\n");

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the transport API for other features, to convert JSON strings to Java objects, you can map automatically by using GSON.
Follow the instructions from [Leveraging the gson library](https://guides.codepath.com/android/leveraging-the-gson-library) and map any response you want from this API.